# Is this relaxed definition of a group true?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a non-empty set and let $*$ be a binary algebraic operation.

Algebraic system $<G, *>$ is a group if

1. $\forall a \in G, \forall b \in G, \forall c \in G: (a * b) * c =  a * (b * c)$
2. $\exists e: \forall a \in G: e * a = a$
3. $\forall a \in G: \exists b \in G : a * b = e$

As you see, only *left* identity element and only *right* inverse element are included in the axioms.

I am supposed to answer if this relaxed definition is the same as the [more common one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29#Definition). First, I tried to prove that left identity implies right identity:

1. Since $e * e = e$, then $e = e^{-1}$.
2. $\forall a^{-1} \in G: a^{-1}*e = a^{-1} * e^{-1} = (e * a)^{-1} = (a)^{-1} = a^{-1}$, therefore right identity exists and equals to left identity.

#### Questions:

1. Am I cheating at the point $a^{-1} * e^{-1} = (e * a)^{-1}$?
2. Is this reduced definition of a group at all equivalent to the [more common one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29#Definition)?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by $a^{-1}$?

Comment: @dani_s I mean that $a^{-1}$ at this point is the right inverse of $a$.

Comment: It might be helpful to you if, instead of tempting yourself to make wrong conclusions by writing $a^{-1}$, you adopted a different notation, say $a^R$, for the right inverse of $a$.

Comment: To prove $a^{-1} * e^{-1} = (e * a)^{-1}$ you need to show that  $(e * a) (a^{-1} * e^{-1}) = e$. It should also be noted that you only proved the following statement: "if $g$ is the right-inverse of some other element of $G$, then $g * e = g$".

Comment: @dani_s Now I understand: $(e * a) * (a ^{-1} * e^{-1}) = e * a * a ^ {-1} * e ^ {-1} = e$ and therefore $a ^ {-1} * e ^ {-1}$ is indeed $(e * a) ^ {-1}$. However, I don't know how to prove that "every element is a right-inverse of some other element".

Comment: If you change your list of axioms to include that for each element, there exists a **left** inverse, then first having proved that the existence of a left identity $e_l$ implies $e_l = e_r$, you can then prove that each element's left inverse is also a right-inverse (hint: you need the result about the identity being "two-sided" to prove that each element's inverse is not only left-sided but also right-sided.

Comment: Your given list of axioms, however, is **not** equivalent to the standard group axioms. You cannot prove, given a left-operating identity and only right-operating inverses, that these inverses are also left-operating. Go to your linked Wikipedia entry and scroll down to *Elementary consequences of the group axioms.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a counterexample consider $G = \{0, 1\}$ and define $*$ by $$0 * 0 = 0 \\ 0 * 1 = 1 \\ 1 * 0 = 0 \\ 1 * 1 = 1$$

Show that your axioms hold; on the other hand $G$ is not a group because for example there is no identity.

Answer (score 8):

It is true that the group axioms can be "weakened" to include:

- associativity
- the existence of a **left** identity for all elements in the group
- for each element in the group, there exists a **left** inverse.

Note that in this weakened definition we need **left identity, left inverses**. Similarly, we can replace both occurrences of **left** above by **right**, so it is also true that associativity plus **right identity, right inverses** suffices. The point is, we need the "sides" of operation of the identity and of inverses to match.

From these "weakened" axioms, we can prove that the left (right) identity is the right (left) identity, and given element $b$ in $G$ such that there exists an element $a$ in $G$ such that  $a*b = e$ it can be shown that $b*a = e$.